# C++ invoking OpenSSL 3.0

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

Is it possible to use C++ to invoke the RSA library of OpenSSL 3.0 to encrypt a string with a private key and then decrypt it with a public key? Are there any runnable examples available for reference?

I want to use EVP_PKEY_encrypt for public key encryption and EVP_PKEY_decrypt for public key decryption. However, I always encounter decryption failures when I run it myself. I would be very grateful if you could provide me with a working demo.

Comment: Encryption with asymmetric keys is done with the *public* key, decryption is done with the *private* key.  There's no point in encrypting something that can be decrypted with a *public* key that's distributed to everyone *publicly*.